# Using *args when plotting in a for loop

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, args

I have a function for graphing:

```
def graph(title, loop, *plotdata): 

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))
    n = 0   
    for i in loop: 
        n += 1
        fig.add_subplot(plt.subplot(4,3,n))
        fig.suptitle('%s' % (title))
        for data in plotdata:
            (data).plot(linewidth=3,label=i)
```

And I call it with:

```
graph('Sector Graph', sectors, sector_return[i])    
# sectors is a list of all S&P sectors
# sector_return is a dict, with S&P sectors as keys and returns each sector as values
```

`sector_return` looks like this:

```
 {'XLB': Date
 2015-01-05         .012
 2015-01-06         .3
 2015-01-07         -.5
 ...
 'XLE': Date
 2015-01-05         -.7
 2015-01-06         -.4
 2015-01-07         -1.6
 ...
```

What is currently happening is that this is plotting the same `sector_return` for all graphs (the last sector in `sectors`). I think my problem is with the nested for loop - but if I take it out and just use plotdata I get:

```
def graph(title, loop, *plotdata): 

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))
    n = 0   
    for i in loop: 
        n+=1
        fig.add_subplot(plt.subplot(4,3,n))
        fig.suptitle('%s' % (title))
        plotdata.plot(linewidth=3, label=i)


In: graph('Sector Graph', sectors,sector_return[i])    

Out: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

My expected output is to have returns of each sector plotted on subplots and being able to add unlimited args (for example my next function `orbital_returns` and have those plotted for each sector as well).

Comment: It is pretty hard to understand your code, but there seems to be something fishy with your `sector_return`. Can you please show what it contains?

Comment: Johan - I made an edit

Comment: What datatype is it? I don't recognize its output format. Is it an ordinary Python `dict` or is it some `pandas` or `numpy` output? Can you format it as Python `repr` does?

Comment: its a pandas dictionary

Comment: Your error in the second case implies it is a tuple of `pandas` data frames. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes that is the case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151685/discussion-between-johanl-and-thomas-mac).